# stopping scroll to top after javascript execution

Tags: javascript

So I have this javascript code snippet that I took off w3 schools but everytime I run it it scrolls my page to the top, but I want it to stay where the user left the page.
I think it acts like this because of the `AddClass` function but I'm not sure.
Does anyone have a fix for this?

**CODE**

```
function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].classList.contains(c)) AddClass(x[i], "show");
        if (c == "all") AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
}

// Show filtered elements
function AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
            element.className += " " + arr2[i];
        }
    }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
            arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("catselector");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn-filter");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

Comment: show us your html. I have a suspicion that your `btn-filter`s are `a` elements with `href="#"`. If that is the case, this href is your problem. In `addEventListener` to your function definition add event variable like so `("click", function (event) {` and in next line add `event.preventDefault()` this will prevent from scrolling to top

Comment: @ciekals11 your suspicion is correct i had a href='#' on that button thnx for helping always nice to have someone else taking a look at your code when you get stuck ;)